# django: give some users less permissions

Tags: django, permissions, authorization

The app is installed at several customers and each installation has several groups and a lot of users.

In the past every user was allowed to use the basic feature *BasicFeature*.

A small new group ("RestrictedUsage") of users should not have the permission to have this *BasicFeature*.

Our current automated update idea looks like this:

1. Create new permission *UseBasicFeature*
2. Give all existing groups the new permission.
3. Create the new group "RestrictedUsage"

Since we have several customers, we need an automated way to handle this.

The above solution does should work, but I don't like it.

I don't like it because installations which don't have a "RestrictedUsage" group need to be modified. Otherwise the users would not be allowed to use *BasicFeature* (which they use since ages).

Has anybody see better way?